# HTML with Hebrew characters displaying weird

Tags: html, css, hebrew

I have a chatbox that displays chats like this

> Username: my chat message
>
> Username2: chat message

But then someone registered using Hebrew characters on his username now when he posts on our chatbox it is displayed incorrectly. It would display like this

> **תירבע: 12345**
>
> Username: my chat message
>
> Username2: chat message

This only happens if he posts numbers. Sample HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Chatbox</title></head>
<body>
    <div><span><a target="_BLANK" style="" href="#">&#1514;&#1497;&#1512;&#1489;&#1506;</a>:</span><span>12345</span></div>
    <div><span><a target="_BLANK" style="" href="#">&#1514;&#1497;&#1512;&#1489;&#1506;</a>:</span><span>this is not numbers so it is displayed correctly</span></div>
    <div><span><a target="_BLANK" style="" href="#">Username1</a>:</span><span>message1</span></div>
    <div><span><a target="_BLANK" style="" href="#">Useraname2</a>:</span><span>message2</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the output of that is this

```
תירבע:12345
תירבע:this is not numbers so it is displayed correctly
Username1:message1
Useraname2:message2
```

How can I make it display correctly so that the username should appear first?

Comment: Could this be because Hindi reads from right to left? You didn't provide enough HTML/CSS to see if there is a rule specifying this.

Comment: I also thinks that's the reason.
<br/>
The html code I posted can replicate my problem 
<br/>

`<span><a target="_BLANK" style="" href="#">&#1514;&#1497;&#1512;&#1489;&#1506;</a>:<span class="">12345</span>`

<br/>
 All I want is to negate the effect of the hindi so that it would not display right to left.

Comment: So… can you provide more HTML/CSS?

Comment: Try adding `direction: ltr;` to your styles.

Comment: @LoganSerman adding `direction: ltr;` has no effect


@Tyler I already added html codes on my question

Comment: Tyler Crompton is correct, this is caused by the right-to-left affinity of the characters. The page layout is actually correct. The reason numbers are treated differently from letters is that the letters have their own affinity which causes the overall to be left-to-right, whereas the numbers do not. If you desire to force this, you could insert a UTF-8 text ordering mark into your page, or use HTML properties (see http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/right-to-left.html for the latter).

Comment: @Borealid Adding `dir="ltr"` solved the problem.  

But is it possible to specify this in the css?  

I already tried `direction: ltr;` and its now working.

Comment: @deceze sorry, You were right its hebrew :)

Comment: @TylerCrompton FYI hindi reads left to right like english. Not right to left

Comment: @footy There was a mistake in the identification of the language. Hebrew does read from right to left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this CSS rule:

```
span a {
    unicode-bidi: embed;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use, in this case,

```
a { unicode-bidi: embed; }
```

In general, set `unicode-bidi: embed` on any element that may contain text with directionality opposite to that of surrounding text. Although e.g. simple embedding of Arabic words in English text (or vice versa) does not usually require this (since the situation is handled by the inherent directionality of letters), it is a useful precaution when digits, punctuation marks, or other directionally neutral characters may be involved.

The HTML counterpart is `<bdo>`, e.g. `<bdo><a ...>...</a></bdo>`, but it is as such unimplemented, so you would need to back it up with `a { unicode-bidi: embed; }` in CSS and, to cover old versions of IE, `document.createElement('bdo')` in JavaScript code.

The `dir=ltr` attribute on the `a` element may have the same effect, but this is a bug in browsers. By the HTML 4.01 specification, it should only affect directionality of directionally neutral text (Hebrew text surely isn’t), and `dir=ltr` is the initial value.

Answer (score -1):

You should look for the code of the language you like to use.

This URL could help you.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: Setting the language should not and does not have an effect on directionality: “User agents must **not** use the `lang` attribute to determine text directionality.” http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.2